# Hot fixes in Release versions of GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have used GIT repository in My iOS Project. I have mainly 4 branches

1. Master
2. Development
3. Release 1
4. Release 2

The Development branch contains current development process and Release 1 and Release 2 branches contains already released versions.

My questions is, recently some bugs reported in the release 2 version and I fixed and commit. But I need to reflect same change in development too. How I do this? Is my branching structure correct?

Comment: you can up to date the dev by checkout to it and merge release 2. IMHO, you shall keep tags for released version on master, and just merge the dev to master and when a release should be done, then tag it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [cherry pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits across from your `release 2` branch over to `release 1`, `development` and/or `master` branches.